# Failed to install PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conda

I tried my best to install **Pytorch** but each and every time I failed to install it.

> Conda version: 4.6.14

I have used **Preview(Nightly)** and **LTS** versions to install but for both of times I have faced the same error like `Solving environment: | Killed` .

> Preview(Nightly) command: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch-nightly`

> LTS command: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch-lts`

Faced error is given in the attached file, please check it.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images, always copy/paste them into your question

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing pytorch into a new environment? problems usually arise when you try to install it into your base environment.

```
conda create -n (NameOfEnviroment) -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
```

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: @Brody_Kretz, Firstly there was a 4.11.x version of conda then I downgraded the conda version into base environment and tried to install. But I have failed and faced above error.

Comment: try moving to conda 4.5.5 then try again, this seems to fix alot of the problems. `conda install conda=4.5.5`

Comment: ok, I am trying to install by following your provided rules. Thanks.

Comment: This suggested solution looks pretty good - have you tried it? Installing new packages into a base environment is a common source of issues, making a new, isolate environment is how conda is intended to be used.

Comment: @ImadadulHaque it's almost never a good idea to downgrade Conda - it is the most important package in the **base** environment is Conda, and older versions often don't interact correctly with the repository.

Comment: @merv , after downgrade the version of cuda(4.6.14), I can install PyTorch successfully. By the way thanks all of you who helps me or try to help me.